# curl returns error (6) occasionally

Tags: bash, curl, ftp

I have a bash script that downloads some files from an ftp server. the problem is that sometimes curl returns errors 6 (can't resolve host) randomly! I can open the ftp via web browser without any problem. I also noticed that the most errors occurs on the first downloads. any idea?

Also I wanted to know that how can I make curl to retry download when these errors occur

Code I used:

```
curl -m 60 --retry 10 --retry-delay 10 --ftp-method multicwd -C - ftp://some_address/some_file --output ./some_file
```

note: I also tried the code without --ftp-method multicwd

OS: CentOS 6.5 64bit

Comment: _"most errors occurs on the first downloads. any idea"_ probably because the host address was put in cache somewhere. Is the ftp server on the local network? on a VPN? On the Internet? Have you tried to ask on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the ftp server isn't on the local network or VPN, it is on the internet (ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov). And I didn't ask my question on any of mentioned websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while [ "$ret" != "0" ]; do curl [your options]; ret=$?; sleep 5; done`

Comment: That would add a delay of 5 seconds even if the download was successful.

Comment: Feel free to replace `sleep 5` with `[ "$ret" != "0" ] && sleep 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are transitional problems with the server and/or DNS, looping might be of some help. This is a particularly good case for the rarely used (?) `until` loop:

```
until curl [your options]; do sleep 5; done
```

---

In addition, if using curl is not mandatory, maybe [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) might be better suited for "unreliable" network connections. From the *man*:

> GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from
>   the Web.  It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as
>   retrieval through HTTP proxies.
>
> [...]
>
> Wget has been designed for robustness over slow or unstable network connections; if a download fails due to
>   a network problem, it will keep retrying until the whole file has been retrieved.  If the server supports
>   regetting, it will instruct the server to continue the download from where it left off.

Comment: thanks. I also used wget, but it acted exactly like curl! I mean returning error as "can't resolve host"

Comment: @gnome Right. As this is probably a problem with the name resolution, `wget` won't be of much help.